# I am Workiing with Keras Package in python on juypter

Tags: python, keras

here is my code which i tried to execute to re scale my matrix or we can say training examples:

```
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_trained_samples=scaler.fit_transform((train_samples).train_reshape(-1,+1))
```

Error is :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-983807c433d9> in <module>
      1 scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
----> 2 scaled_trained_samples=scaler.fit_transform((train_samples).train_reshape(-1,+1))

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'train_reshape'
```

Comment: simply say `.reshape` or `scaled_trained_samples=scaler.fit_transform((train_samples).reshape(-1,+1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams `train_samples` is an numpy array. `train_reshape` is a method from scaler. You could do `scaler.train_reshape()` for example but not `train_samples.train_reshape()`.

To do that just try:

```
scaled_trained_samples=scaler.fit_transform(train_samples.reshape(-1,+1))
```